# Xocde上で指定したviewの色と、Illustrator上で指定して画像として出力した色が一致しない。

Tags: xcode

Xcode上で指定したviewの色と、Illustrator上で指定して画像として出力した色が一致しません。

Xcode上のカラーパレットで、Viewの背景色を
R:230 G:230 B:230

としたものと、

Illustrator上の図形の色を
R:230 G:230 B:230
としてPNGで書き出したものの

色を一致させたいのですが、
ずれてしまします。（貼り付けた時に色が異なる）

何が悪いのでしょうか？

ちなみに、
IllustratorのカラーモードはRGBです。

Comment: ずれているとありますが、配置した状態でスクリーンショットを取って、それぞれの色のRGB値を確認するとどうなりますか？それと、書き出したPNGのRGB値は別のソフトで開くなりして確認したのでしょうか？

Comment: 異なっていました。Xcodeのカラーパレットで「Device RGB」というのを選べるところがあって、それにしたら解決しました。

Comment: なるほど。判明した原因や解決策をご自身で回答として投稿していただけませんか？そのうえで回答左側のチェックマークをクリックすることで、質問が解決済みというマークになります。

Comment: ご回答、ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcodeのカラーパレットで「Device RGB」というのを選べるところがあって、
それにしたら解決しました。